# Sort list of tuples based on matches in another

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort two lists of tuples by matches in each other. The tuples contain data scraped from sports betting websites. I have written some code that matches the entries in each list and appends them to a new list. The issue I'm having is finding a sorting function that can search based on imperfect matches, for example there may be an extra white space in a name or there may by shortened team names such as 'Nth Queensland Cowboys' in sportsbet_list as opposed to North Queensland Cowboys in list_finale. See the lists below:

```
list_finale = [[('Canterbury Bulldogs ', '3.25'), ('South Sydney Rabbitohs', '1.34')], [('Parramatta Eels ', '1.79'), ('Wests Tigers', '2.02')], [('Melbourne Storm ', '1.90'), ('Sydney Roosters', '1.90')], [('Gold Coast Titans ', '1.86'), ('Newcastle Knights', '1.94')], [('New Zealand Warriors ', '1.39'), ('North Queensland Cowboys', '2.95')], [('Cronulla Sharks ', '1.68'), ('Penrith Panthers', '2.18')], [('St. George Illawarra Dragons ', '1.45'), ('Manly Sea Eagles', '2.74')], [('Canberra Raiders ', '1.63'), ('Brisbane Broncos', '2.26')]]


sportsbet_list = [[('Cronulla Sharks', '1.64'), ('Penrith Panthers', '2.27')], [('Canterbury Bulldogs', '3.30'), ('South Sydney Rabbitohs', '1.33')], [('Melbourne Storm', '1.90'), ('Sydney Roosters', '1.90')], [('New Zealand Warriors', '1.40'), ('Nth Queensland Cowboys', '2.90')], [('St George Illawarra Dragons', '1.45'), ('Manly Sea Eagles', '2.75')], [('Gold Coast Titans', '1.85'), ('Newcastle Knights', '1.95')], [('Canberra Raiders', '1.60'), ('Brisbane Broncos', '2.30')], [('Parramatta Eels', '1.90'), ('Wests Tigers', '1.90')], [('Sydney Roosters', '1.35'), ('St George Illawarra Dragons', '3.20')], [('Melbourne Storm', '1.25'), ('New Zealand Warriors', '4.00')], [('Canterbury Bulldogs', '1.56'), ('Nth Queensland Cowboys', '2.40')], [('Penrith Panthers', '2.20'), ('South Sydney Rabbitohs', '1.67')], [('Wests Tigers', '1.67'), ('Gold Coast Titans', '2.20')], [('Brisbane Broncos', '1.70'), ('Cronulla Sharks', '2.15')], [('Manly Sea Eagles', '1.85'), ('Canberra Raiders', '1.95')], [('Newcastle Knights', '1.80'), ('Parramatta Eels', '2.00')]]
```

The current code I am using to sort these lists is given  below:

```
list_n = []

list_n1 = []

for a in sportsbet_list:
    for b in list_finale:
        if b[0][0] == a[0][0] and b[1][0] == a[1][0]:
            list_n.append(a)
            list_n1.append(b)
```

This works but only when the team-names are exactly the same.

Basically I need a matching function that accepts `b[0][0] == a[0][0] and b[1][0] == a[1][0]`: if they are 85% similar or something like that.

I am very new to coding so any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining similarity?

Comment: you can use `strip` to remove whitespaces and for shortnames I think you'll have to make lookup `dict`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of routes you can take. The first is probably the more strict matching solution, while the second is kind of fuzzy.

- Stricter method (Normalize the input, then do a normal sort)

This solution may or may not work for you needs, but it's basically this: you need to get these names as close as possible to the desired state. Here's a sample that hopefully illustrates what you might do:

```py
team_bet_list = [('Canterbury Bulldogs ', '3.25'), ('South Sydney Rabbitohs', '1.34')] 

def normalize_team(item):
    substitutions = {
      'north': 'nth',
      'south': 'sth',  # etc
    }
    words = [word.lower() for word in item[0].strip()]
    return (words, item[1])  # returning a new tuple -- you might even want to return the original non-normalized value, if that's important to you

normalized_values = [normalize(pair) for pair in team_bet_list]

# Now you should be able to sort these, but it'll take some experimentation to find the best normalization approach
```

- The second option is to use a fuzzy kind of match. There are two that come to mind. First is to use the levenstien distance, which basically tells you how far away any two strings are, based on the number of character changes that need to happen. (e.g. rope -> boat has a distance of 3 ( { r-> b, p -> a, e->t}. Using this, you could then try to find the closest match in each list and assume it's the proper value. Or, you could try a library like fuzzywuzzy. This worked decently for me before. See https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy